# Force the footer to stick at the bottom of the page on all resolutions

Tags: html, css

I am currently creating a scrolling (long) page. I have encountered a problem with the footer though. Since the wrapper has an absolute position, the footer goes behind the wrapper, instead of sticking at the bottom of the page. How can I make it so that my footer will stick at the bottom of the page on all resolutions?

http://jsfiddle.net/Kzh7z/

You can see the little blue part of it sticking behind the wrapper.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
</div> <!-- end wrapper -->
<footer>
<div id="footer">
<div class="copyright">
<p>footer copyright blah etc</p>
</div>
</div>
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
background: #CCC;
border-top-left-radius: 25px;
border-top-right-radius: 25px;
width: 1000px;
height: 1200px;
position: absolute;
}

#footer {
background: #0A59C2;
border-top: 5px solid #06489E;
width: 100%;
height: 85px;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: When viewing your question please have a look at the right. Under the topic "Related" you'll find dozens of questions like yours and appropriate answers. ;-)

Comment: Sorry, I'll do that next time. The related answers did not really help me that much, but I'll take a look at any I have not viewed before.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Updated to reflect what was discussed in the comments.

This will keep #footer at the bottom and keep #wrapper above it. `position: absolute` is not necessary for #wrapper.

```
#wrapper {
    background: #CCC;
    border-top-left-radius: 25px;
    border-top-right-radius: 25px;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1200px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    z-index: 1;
}

#photoContent {
    border: 10px solid #F5F5F5;
    box-shadow: 0 0 7px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 781px;
    height: 231px;
    background: #FFF;
    margin-top: 12px;
}

#footer {
    background: #0A59C2;
    border-top: 5px solid #06489E;
    width: 100%;
    height: 85px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but having the footer scroll the entire page is a little annoying in my opinion - I wouldn't like to see the copyright stuff when browsing a website. I just want it to stick at the bottom of the page. Thanks though.

Comment: Ok, yeah I misunderstood what you wanted.

Comment: If the browser height is greater than 1200px, you still want the footer at the bottom of the page, even though there will be a gap between #wrapper and #footer?

Comment: Well the wrapper needs to have a large height. I want the wrapper to look like it's "coming out" of the footer, so I don't want a gap. Before there was not a gap when the wrapper did not have the absolute position.

Comment: Just curious, why does #wrapper need to be `position: absolute`?

Comment: I have elements in the wrapper that I need to be pushed down, but if I do so, the whole wrapper is pushed for some reason.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, using `position: relative` instead of `position: absolute` should have the same effect on the contents of #wrapper without affecting #wrapper itself.

Comment: Everything is great now, except the one element at the top (#photoContent) will not push down. http://jsfiddle.net/zb8hb/

Comment: Here ya go: http://jsfiddle.net/zb8hb/1/. You just had to add `overflow: auto` to the wrapper. It wasn't pushing down because of what's called "collapsing margins", which is a "feature" of HTML I wish would go away.

Comment: Thanks I believe it worked! My friend with a very large screen size still hasn't replied, but I'll cross my fingers it is at the bottom. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Sure, no problem. Feel free to post in here again if it's not working.